# One time password security risk

Tags: java, security, web

We are developing a web application where user has to input a One Time Password (which we email to the users) to complete an operation. However, if a malicious user develops a bot and guesses the pattern in which we generate the One Time Password, he can input some random email id and by not even looking at the email he can confirm the transaction. That way he can attack the system with false confirmations. Can someone please let us know how people deal with this?

Thanks

Comment: don't use a predictable one-time password generator.

Comment: Not being facetious, but simply don't generate the passwords in any sort of pattern.

Comment: Generate unpredictable one-time passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your random one-time passwords have the same entropy as regular passwords, this should be just as fine as any other password solution.

Here's an example password generation snippet which should be fairly unpredictable:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;

class Test {

    public static String generatePassword() {
        String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                     + "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                     + "0123456789!@%$%&^?|~'\"#+="
                     + "\\*/.,:;[]()-_<>";

        final int PW_LENGTH = 20;
        Random rnd = new SecureRandom();
        StringBuilder pass = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < PW_LENGTH; i++)
            pass.append(chars.charAt(rnd.nextInt(chars.length())));
        return pass.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(generatePassword());
        System.out.println(generatePassword());
        System.out.println(generatePassword());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> `Qp';Md#93Dxh\0|%%Ny7`
>   `oqvntn2).~W@%P'EM*AS`
>   `WEo2sz2Sm~a'm=Ss&Lu[`

Comment: I completely agree with you. But the problem here is, we expect user to key in the password back in our site. So we can use such huge password. Imagine we were to use only [a-zA-Z0-9] which is 6 characters long, do you think it is secure? If it is not completely secure, is it correct to implement some policy like "not more that 100 requests per IP address"?

Comment: A 6 digit alpha/numeric password sounds like a bad idea... Hard for me to judge though.

Comment: @Gopal isn't the point of a "one time" password that the user doesn't have to type it?  Either it's copy/pasted or it's embeded in the url.  Since it can only be used one time, it shouldn't matter that it might show up in log files or whatever after they click the link.  It only works once.

Answer (score 4):

Just use random password without patterns. The advantage is you can make the password longer if it is clickable in the mail because the user doesn't have to type it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing from your question description that the "one time password" you're generating is actually some form of crude encryption where you reverse the process in order to figure out which account they're referring to.

This is the wrong approach, the one time password needs to be random so there's no possible way to compute the password based on the email address.  You'll need to store the one time password (preferably hashed) with the account info in the database and use that for looking up.

Answer (score 2):

Generate your passwords using a high entropy source - in unix try /dev/urandom - that will effectively give you one-time passwords.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it. Send them a *URL link* with a huge password (security ticket) in it as a URL argument, and arrange your end so that if that argument is present and correct (i) they are logged in and (ii) the validity of the UUID ceases, either immediately or within a day or two of sending it. May take a bit of doing depending on your container but it's far more secure. I use java.util.UUID for this, nice and long.

Comment: EJP, thanks for the response. Actually, we also have a plan to text message OTP to the user. If we generate a huge key it will irritate user. Also, there are several banks which generate OTP as the transaction passwords. How are they confident about this? At last they are financial institutions and they need to worry more about this? Can you throw some light on this?

Comment: @Gopal if you generate a huge key *in a link,* and all they have to do is click it, how exactly is that going to 'irritate the user'? *No* typing. I have no idea how banks can possibly be confident about OTPs of less than huge length. I'm not.

Comment: pardon if I'm not clear. What I meant was we try to send a text message with OTP to user's mobile.

Comment: @Gopal but in your question you said that it was emailed, not text messaged.  Email works better because you can have a link with the password that they can just click and not have to type.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct you have a big security hole in the scheme but you identified the wrong hole!

Your problem is that you email it out-- email isn't secure.

As for guessing the problem that should be statistically impossible as long as you use a long enough password.  You might want to lock people out after they guess wrong 100 times.

One trick I've seen is asking a user for a Paypal or bank account number.  You then make a few deposits for random amounts.  So they see deposits for say 34, 91, and 82 cents.  They then use those numbers as a password!  Pretty clever huh?

Answer (score 0):

Implement a one-time password which is not computationally feasible to guess.

For example, use a random string generator to generate a string 15 characters long, using a pool of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and numbers.

This results in 62^15 possible combinations, which would be extremely difficult for a brute force program to crack.

Answer (score 0):

Having a 6 digit random number as an OTP is not a security risk *as long as you invalidate the OTP after the first use*. To guess a 6 digit number in a single try is neigh on impossible. And since you only get one try, brute-force isn't something to worry about either. Just make sure you generate a truly random number, e.g. using SecureRandom.

So, steps to take:

1. List item
2. Generate a 6-digit random number OTP
3. Correlate it to an account (so e.g. user enters email and OTP)
4. On each auth attempt of a given user email, invalidate the OTP, whether the login was successful or not

Using Java, you could use the following method to generate the OTP:

```
public static final String getOTP(int length) {

    Random r = new SecureRandom();
    return String.valueOf(r.nextInt((int)Math.pow(10, length)));
}
```

Hope that makes sense.